# Visual Studio Code not honoring .gitignore in git tab

Tags: git, gitignore

I've appropriately configured a .gitignore file and put it in the base directory of my project, but when I go to the git tab of Visual Studio Code it does not ignore the folder that I'm trying to ignore and therefore is suggesting that there are changes for 4000+ files that I don't care about (the folder that I'm trying to ignore is a virtual environment for python).

Has anyone else successfully gotten the git tab to ignore changes using the .gitignore file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gitignore doesn't affect the files which are **already** tracked.

To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use `git rm --cached <dir>`. It removes the file from the staging area entirely, but doesn't delete the directory from disk; instead leaves the directory as it is.

Comment: Or `git rm --cached -r <glob_expression>` to remove all tracked files matching a pattern

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was I right clicked any one of the file(while the git tab is selected) under `changes` menu which I didn't wanted and was also in one of the directories mentioned in the `.gitignore` file. After right clicking I selected `Add file to .gitignore` and boom all the unwanted 5k files went from git tab. And I was happy :)